# How to rearrange windows in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: taskbar

How to rearrange the taskbar's windows location in the taskbar? When my chrome browser restarts, it randomizes the Windows arrangement and since I use a lot of windows and tabs, it gets really confusing.

P.S I never combine them, so I am talking about the windows themselves, not the thumbnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) to reorder windows in taskbar by dragging.

Answer (score 1):

Taskbar Windows (Icons) just go the last position on the left side of the taskbar, that is, the right side of the currently running App icons in the taskbar.

If you have several apps open, and then let us say Chrome was first, so the Chrome Icon is far left, and then you close Chrome to restart it, then the Chrome Icon is now at the right side of all the icons (representing Apps running).

The behaviour is not random, but you cannot "keep" the original position of any given given icon. Windows does not know if you are restarting an app or closing it for good in this session.

This is the normal Windows Behaviour.

Comment: But they can easily add the option to rearrange them manually, or at least there must be some tweaks that could do that trick

Comment: Try (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-best-tools-tweak-customize-windows-10/#:~:text=Ultimate%20Windows%20Tweaker%20is%20a%20lightweight%20%28495KB%29%20and,200%20Windows%20tweaks%20for%20you%20to%20play%20with.)  . There are some re-ordering option but these need drag and drop. See it helps.